# Finding a specific pattern in a boolean array

Tags: python, boolean

I am working on a project and am getting stuck on the following bit : I have a boolean array and I would like to determine if a specific pattern is present in this array.

For example, let's imagine I have this boolean array : [True, False, False, True, False, False, True, False, True, True, True] and I would like to know if it contains the following pattern [False, False, True, False].

My first idea was to loop through all values of the boolean array, define a variable that counts the number of consecutive "False" then loops again to find if "True" is following that sequence, etc... But it seems a bit tedious and I imagine there is a better way to do this...

Any advice would be very welcomed !
Thank you

Comment: This is very similar to finding a substring in a string problem. Look at [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-string-substring-another/) and you should be able to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to convert the array to a string of `f` and `t` characters, then use string search to find the desired pattern.  For example:

```
def bool_list_to_str(bool_list):
    return ''.join('ft'[i] for i in bool_list)
```

You can call this function to convert both your array and your search pattern to strings.  Then you can use `s.find(p)` to search for pattern `p` in string `s`.

Note that this uses one character per bool value, so the string will have the same length as the bool list, and the indices will match.  It also uses a minimal amount of string memory.

Comment: Thank you, that works really well actually and very easy to implement ! Cheers !

Comment: @ms518 Great, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You can join them as string and check for substring:

```
super_list = [True, False, False, True, False, False, True, False, True, True, True]
sub_list = [False, False, True, False]

super_list_as_str = ''.join(map(str, super_list))
sub_list_as_str = ''.join(map(str, sub_list))

if sub_list_as_str in super_list_as_str:
    print('Sub string')
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a great method, very efficient

Answer (score 0):

I am starting with programming then my code is not optimize. But it's very easy to understand:

1.- Create a list with all the combinations of the array with lenght n

2.- Make a comparision of the pattern with the list you have create.

```
# a is the array you want to check with
a = [True, False, False, True, False, False, True, False, True, True, True]
# b is the array you want to check
b = [False, True, False, False]
# patterns is the list with all the patterns in the array
patterns = []
for i in range(len(a)-(len(b)-1)):
    patterns.append((a[i:(len(b)+i)]))

# Check if b is in the list you have create.
b in patterns
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've gone with another method but will try out yours as well